# File not found. After adding 301 redirect - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, 301-redirect, apache2

I've added a permanent 301 redirect to my Magento 2 store to remove `.html` 
from my category and product urls by adding the following code to my website .conf file - I'm using Apache

```
redirectMatch 301 ^(.*)\.html $1
```

The redirect works fine as I don't get any 404 errors for existing products and categories that have .html in the url but now I have another problem.

I am now getting 404 errors for static content even though I have deployed them on the frontend and backend/admin

If I remove the 301 everything loads a normal. Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

[image: Admin Sales > Order]

[image: Product page image]

Comment: Magento calling many `.html` files in admin and front side especially on the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the configuration just add this to your .htaccess of website .conf file so only the URI is rewritten and not the loading of .html files.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^index.php/?(.*).html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```